# How to configure ADFS to manage all aplications authentication requirements?

Tags: windows, forms-authentication, windows-authentication, adfs2.0

Hi Guys I have question about ADFS 2.0.

I have several applications managed  by ADFS 2.0  how can I configure ADFS so it will allow this:

1. Application A  authenticating users from the windows domain.
2. Application B  authenticating users using form authentication.
3. Application C  authenticating users from the network with windows authentication, outside the company network (extranet) with form authentications.

Is it possible to achieve this with one ADFS installation??

If the answer is yes could you guys provide samples of the configuration or at least which book teach how to achieve this goal.

Thank you very much in advance.

JV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first two, refer [ADFS : using the WAUTH parameter](http://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/2013/05/adfs-using-wauth-parameter.html).

Essentially, you add the correct wauth to the application's web.config.

There are some links at the bottom for further reading.

For the last, you need an ADFS and an ADFS proxy. Then use split DNS.

- Extranet --> Proxy --> Forms
- Intranet --> ADFS --> IWA

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, just one last thing do you have a link about how to install the ADFS proxy?

Comment: There's quite a few e.g. http://www.edunnewijk.nl/fatshark/index.php?/archives/349-ADFS-Proxy-Step-by-Step-Install-Guide.html